# C++ throw scope

Tags: c++, exception, scope

When switching compilers my old'n trusted `throw` code (example below) fails. I'm guessing that it is the `err` variable scope that is the problem? What happens is that when trying to access the string part of `err` it has been deallocated. What would be a better way of doing something like this using a custom exception class?

```
if (someErrorHappend)
{
    std::stringstream err;
    err << "Some error #" << GetLastError() << ".";
    throw SomeCustomException("MyClass", "MyFunc", err.str().c_str());
}
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? What does the exception do with its third parameter?

Comment: The constructor for `SomeCustomException` needs to make a copy of the string. You'll just want to be careful not to throw an exception while trying to throw an exception. When properly implemented using C++11 move semantics, this should not be a problem.

Comment: Suggestion: start by listing the requirements of the exception class. What information must it carry (if any)? Then write that class, using best practices when writing its constructors and copy/move operators.
From then on, it will all just flow naturally.

Comment: @RichardHodges: suggestion: do not write any copy/move operator or a destructor (aka Rule Of Zero).

Comment: @Matthieu M yup, that's part of 'best practice'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c_str` is a non-owning pointer, so you shouldn't pass it to the constructor that will retain it directly.

To fix the problem, simply adjust the constructor `SomeCustomException` to accept a `std::string` instead of a `char *`. The `char *` will be converted to a `string`, which is an owning object.

In the future, you can migrate code by removing the `c_str()` call and leaving only `err.str()`. The compiler will apply C++11 move semantics to remove one copy operation.

Don't worry about running out of memory. The `stringstream` code is already allocating on the heap for its internal string, and there's no difference between that and the exception constructor — both run before the `throw`, and if you ran out of memory beforehand, you should already be in an exception handling state anyway.

Comment: Will this work as intended with C++03 also or does the copy semantics only work with C++11 since you explicitly mention this - I have to support C++03.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen Yes, move semantics are a non-breaking change (aside from some pathological cases, which `string` is most definitely not).